# DNS wildcard subdomain error

Tags: dns, opensuse-12.2

I am trying to make wildcard subdomain configuration on my VM with SUSE. 
While trying to enter the record (I am using vi) *.host IN A  to the .zone file, the line is turning in red and after restarting the named.service it's trowing an error that there is a problem and the zone won't be loaded.

Here is the .zone file:

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN domain.com.
@    IN   SOA  dns1.com.  hostmaster.com. (
              2001062501 ; serial
              21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
              3600       ; retry after 1 hour
              604800     ; expire after 1 week
              86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
     IN   NS   dns2.com.
     IN   NS   dns1.com.
dns1 IN   A    <ip of dns>
dns2 IN   A    <ip of dns>
domain  IN   A    <ip of system>
. IN A <ip of system>
*.domain. IN A <ip of system>           -> here is the problem
domain.com.   IN   A    <ip of system>
*     IN    CNAME domain
```

Comment: Surely it also says _what_ the problem is? If not, try `named-checkzone domain.com /path/to/my.zone`?

Comment: Either you're missing a `.` or you have one where it shouldn't be (my guess).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem line is out of zone.  Your $ORIGIN is `domain.com`so everything must be relative (no trailing dots) or everything must end with `domain.com.` (with a trailing dot).  As in your SOA record, keep in mind that @ means "current origin", i.e., `domain.com`

You also should get rid of the line with just '.', that's a root reference that is silently being ignored.

A couple of your records are not doing what you expect and your NS records are bogus as well (I'll assume a bad edit/replace for all those).

You may also need to Google "dns wildcard production rules" to understand how to do wildcards properly, there are a couple unexpected things if you make assumptions about how the wildcard is expanded (it doesn't quite work like regular expressions).